# Crystal Reports is not showing negative numbers

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, negative-number

I have a report that has been working perfectly up until now. There is a "Tax" field, which uses the following formula to calculate:

> Sum ({JBIS.PrevTax}, {JBIS.BillNumber}) + Sum ({JBIS.TaxAmount}, {JBIS.BillNumber})

The formula works except for when the conclusion is a negative number. We need it to print even the negatives here. Currently, it displays "0.00" if the answer is negative.

Comment: What number formatting do you have that field set to use?

Comment: We figured out that it was actually an issue with the data we entered in the software running the report. All of the common mistakes were checked (such as how the number was formatted) and it was all correct, which is why I was baffled.

Comment: Are you using any round functions?

Comment: No, Siva, we are not. But this has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that it was actually an issue with the data we entered in the software running the report.